# How to draw a filled circle in Borland C++?

Tags: c++, drawing, c++builder

I'm stuck at my program using Borland C++. I want to draw a filled circle in Red, at least big enough for a old man's eyes to see.

```
xRed = random( 160 );
yRed = random( 120 );
PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ xRed ][ yRed ] = clRed;
```

I have this code written which only gives me a very very small dot that even my perfect
eyes could not see clearly. Please advice.

Comment: What execution environment?  Windows?  MSDOS?  What library do you want to use?

Comment: `at least big enough for a old man's eyes to see` that depends on how old the man is! ;) Just kidding..

Comment: If you're using BGI you could use `fillellipse`, but it looks like you're trying to draw onto some bitmap, so any generic circle-filling routine should work for you.

Comment: How about setting the pixels around pixel (xRed, yRed) to red forming a circle. That way it would be more visible.

Comment: I'm using, I have no idea wat I'm using... I'm on Windows XP, my program gives me a User graphic interface.

Comment: @jfs, how do i set the pixels around it to be red too? The red dot is a randomly generated.

Comment: Assuming x,y is randomly generated, then pixels around this point is (x-1, y), (x,y-1), (x+1, y), (x,y+1). Then maybe you can set `PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ x-1][ y ] = clRed`.

Answer (score 1):

Though i can't remember whether this work with circle it works with rectangle for sure.check something like this

```
setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLUE);
Circle(x,y,radious);
```

Comment: where you want to draw the circle

Comment: inside the PaintBox1, It is a canvas of size 160 *120

Comment: it will draw on the current window.according to center x,y and radious.

Comment: My program says that undefined function setfillstyle

Comment: See the header file for the function

Comment: include the appropriate header file.did you include graphics.h

Answer (score 1):

PaintBox1->Canvas-> suggests to me that you are using Turbo C++ Explorer, which was the free version of Borland C++ Builder and is using the VCL framework.

If that is the case, try this code:

```
   PaintBox1->Canvas->Brush->Color = clRed; // Set the fill color
   PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed;   // Set the border color

   int xRed = random( 160 );
   int yRed = random( 120 );
   int radius = 40;

   PaintBox1->Canvas->Ellipse(xRed - radius, yRed - radius, xRed + radius, yRed + radius);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was `FillEllipse()` procedure (which indeed draws a filled ellipse), if my memory serves me...